# Is there a JS API to get information about headers that were sent?

Tags: javascript, http, browser, http-headers

Of course I can set headers when issuing requests programmatically, i.e. for Ajax calls.

But is there a way to let the browser do its thing and access the request headers for resources in a document, similar to timing information provided by the [Resource Timing API](http://www.w3.org/TR/resource-timing/)?

I'd like to know the complete set of headers the browser used when requesting the document and its resources.

Comment: document.lastModified echos the most useful one, document.contentType is usually of minimal help...

Comment: @dandavis I believe this is what the server returned. I'd like to know the complete set of headers the browser used when requesting the document and its resources.